# setting properties only if present in *.properties file

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I am using an XML file to setup dependencies that looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">

  <bean id="aClassInstance" class="a.package.AClass">
    <property name="prop1" value="${prop.1}" />
    <property name="prop2" value="${prop.2}" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I am using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to replace the `"${}"` placeholders with values from a `*.properties` file. I would like to be able to setup a property in a bean **only if** the corresponding property in the `*.properties` file is present. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyOverrideConfigurer` allows you to setup properties using a `beanName.property = value` syntax. If a specific property is not present in the properties file, no setter is called by Spring.

You can thus use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to replace placeholders in constructors, and `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` to setup optional properties. You can use `PropertyOverrideConfigurer.setIgnoreInvalidKeys(true)` if there are placeholders not corresponding to a `beanName.property` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need default value if property doesn't exist, then you could try something like:

```
 <bean id="aClassInstance" class="a.package.AClass">
    <property name="prop1" value="${prop.1:default}" />
    <property name="prop2" value="${prop.2:default}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. What if I need the setter not being called if the property is missing?

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do the same. There could be hacks around.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to `true` on `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and it would not raise exception when property which you are trying to inject is missing in `*.properties` file.

Comment: According the documentation, this will leave the placeholders as they are. Wouldn't that be a problem when the value `${prop.1}` is passed to the setter of `AClass`?

Comment: Yes that is true. And you do not want to chang or handle anything in setters?

Comment: Yes, no setter should be called when the corresponding property is not present in the `*.properties` file. Thx for your time, I ahve already found the answer (already posted it).